# How to pass Login With Google Process in Cocoa WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I am developing a cocoa app for Mac OSX. It's a basic browser application and I use webview component.

In the page I want to connect, there is standard Login with Google Account button in order to login with my existing Google Account. When I clicked on this button nothing happens.

The same functionality works properly when I visited the same page by using Safari or any other browser but there is no reaction on webview component.

I've checked the action behind the Google's login button and here is the JS code.

```
onclick="return Dialog.Login.loginWithGoogle(false, 'https://www.mywebsite.com/-/oauth2callback', 'https://www.mywebsite.com/')"
```

As a part of the standard oauth process the process also has many redirections after this URL is called and normally should be completed at my site's login screen as expected. However, webview doesn't handle this.

Please note that the web site I am trying to connect in my webview is not belong to me and I have no control on it.

I checked many solutions on the web for 2 days but nothing helped.

Any help/hint will be appreciated.

Comment: If the WebView isn't redirecting, isn't this an OAuth2 problem and not an ObjC one?

Comment: When I clicked on the button nothing happens in the web view. If I let it to open the link in normal browser by [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url]; then all redirections are done in a row but then it can't come back to the initial page (which is still in my web view) and authorization is not completed...

Comment: This seems basically because webview is not behaving like normal browser and cannot open a second tab in order to let google to complete all redirection and authorization in a new tab...